# Overloading method of comparison for custom class

Tags: php, object, comparison, overloading

I want to overload methods of comparison for a personnal class.

For example if I write this : $object1 < $object2
Php will use this function :

```
function compare($a, $b){
    if($a->attribute == $b->attribute){return 0;}
    else{return $a->attribute > $b->attribute ? 1 : -1;}
}
```

Is there a way to do this ?

I already seen [this](http://webreflection.blogspot.fr/2008/06/from-future-php-javascript-like-number.html) and [this](http://pecl.php.net/package/operator) but I can't use these solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PECL solution you point to above is your only option.  PHP does not provide operator overloading as available in other languages.

Comment: Ok, that's not the answer I expected but thanks for your answer ;)

Now I've to implement another solution